# Spring Kafka, manual committing in different threads with multiple acks?

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-kafka

I am trying to ack kafka Message consumed via a batchListener in a separate thread; Using @Async for the called method.

```js
 @KafkaListener( topics = "${topic.name}" ,containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryBatch", id ="${kafkaconsumerprefix}")
        public void consume(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records,Acknowledgment ack) {  
        records.forEach(record -> asynchttpCaller.posttoHttpsURL(record,ack));
  }
```

and my Async code is below where KafkaConsumerException extends BatchListenerFailedException

```js
@Async
 public void posttoHttpsURL(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record,Acknowledgment ack)
 {
     
   try {                                
   //post to http
   ack.acknowledge();
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
    throw new KafkaConsumerException("Exception occured in sending via HTTPS",record);

   }
}
```

With the below Configuration

```
 @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
    bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
    StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
    StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, 
   "read_committed");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 
    maxpollRecords);
    return props;
 }

  @Bean
   public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
  }



  /**
 * Batch Listener */
 
   @Bean
   @Primary
   public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> 
    kafkaListenerContainerFactoryBatch (
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,  
    ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
    KafkaOperations<? extends Object, ? extends Object> template ) {
  
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> 
        factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true); 
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer = new 
        DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template);    
        ExponentialBackOff fbo = new ExponentialBackOff(); 
        fbo.setMaxElapsedTime(maxElapsedTime);
        fbo.setInitialInterval(initialInterval);
        fbo.setMultiplier(multiplier);
        RecoveringBatchErrorHandler errorHandler = new 
        RecoveringBatchErrorHandler(recoverer, fbo);
        factory.setBatchErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        factory.setConcurrency(setConcurrency);
        return factory;
  }
```

This ack.acknowledge() acknowledges every record in that batch if using AckMode as MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and will ack only if all are success when AckMode is MANUAL.
The Scenario I have is --> there will be certain httpcalls that results in success and certain that gets a timeout both in the same batch; if the errored Messages has a greater offset than the successful one ;even the succesful one is not getting acknowledged and is being duplicated.

Not sure why BatchListenerFailedException always throws the whole batch though I give specifically the record that errored.

Any suggestions on how to implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not process asynchronously because offsets could be committed out-of-sequence.

`BatchListenerFailedException`  will only work if thrown on the listener thread.